# Как сделать автоматическую прокрутку скролла, при открытии блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Проблему можно посмотреть наглядно на гиф:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать автоматическую прокрутку скролла, при открытии блока? Т.е. я скрываю блок (здесь все хорошо). Но когда я нажимаю еще раз на эту же кнопку что бы обратно открыть блок, скролл автоматически не прокручивается. и Этот блок получается не видно. Как исправить?

Я уже перепробовал якоря и тому подобное, не получается...

Comment: разметку, для которой вы пытаетесь это сделать, вместе со скриптом - тут можно вставлять сниппеты прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Верните все условия в скрипте в первоначальное состояние после повторного нажатия. У вас не все возвращается.

Answer (score 2):

**Посмотреть можно тут - [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mvqvjbkq/1/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
    #trigger,
    #trigger2 {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      background: #FFCECE;
      color: #555;
      font-size: 150%;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #trigger {
      top: 0px;
    }

    #trigger2 {
      bottom: 0px;
    }

    #block {
      display: none;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 3px solid #eee;
      text-align: center;
    }

  </style>

  <body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <div id="trigger">Кнопка</div>

    <div id="block">
      <img src="http://www.fndvisions.org/img/cutecat.jpg" alt="Изображение">
    </div>

    <div id="trigger2">Кнопка 2</div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Первый вариант. Выравнивание блока сверху. */
        var triggerButton = $('#trigger'); // Кнопка
        var block = $('#block'); // Блок 
        var blockPadding = 10; // Отсутп кона сверху стайта
        var scrollSpeed = 300; // Скорость прокрутки
        var slideSpeed = 300; // Скорость прокрутки

        triggerButton.click(function(event) {
          if (block.is(":hidden")) {
            block.slideDown(slideSpeed, function() {
              marginTop = block.offset().top - blockPadding;
              $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: marginTop
              }, scrollSpeed);
            });
          } else {
            block.slideUp(slideSpeed);
          }
        });

        /* Второй вариант. Выравнивание блока снизу. */
        triggerButton = $('#trigger2'); // Кнопка
        block = $('#block'); // Блок 
        blockPadding = 30; // Отсутп кона сверху стайта
        scrollSpeed = 300; // Скорость прокрутки
        slideSpeed = 300; // Скорость прокрутки

        triggerButton.click(function(event) {
          if (block.is(":hidden")) {
            block.slideDown(slideSpeed, function() {
              marginTop = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - block.offset().top + blockPadding;
              $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: marginTop
              }, scrollSpeed);
            });
          } else {
            block.slideUp(slideSpeed);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```